How to Bypass Jupyter Authentication Page and Use Token-Based Authentication in Docker?
I want to integrate jupyterhub in my web application so ,I’ve launched Jupyter in a Docker container using a specific image and created multiple users. I want to authenticate these users using tokens without displaying the Jupyter authentication page. Is there a way to achieve this? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!.
i have launched the jupyter in docker and i have created users using jupyter api's and able to login jupyter using user credentials, i have achived this. i want to bypass authentication using token , so i can easily integrate jupyter in my application !

This does not sound like a wise idea from a security perspective. However, if you wanted to effectively give anyone access without authentication, you would need a reverse proxy that injects an Authorization request header, with the token as it's payload, between the client and the upstream. See the answer here to understand what this means.

hi Daniel , actually we can able to create individual user token , so each user have token, by using this we can able to login particular user jupyter lab. it should work,  but for me its not working, do i need to add/modify jupyter_config.py file settings for this ?

Wait, are you saying you want to send requests from your web application to jupyterhub? If that is the case, you still just need to send the correct Authorization header token and hit the correct API endpoint. Follow this documentation for how to make requests to the JH API.
